# I am unsure how to use fscanf properly

Tags: c

This program should get in input a number and calculate the average value between a student's marks. This program works only with the former student, but not with the following ones. I think there's a mistake with that  fscanf. Can anybody help?

```
int main ()
{
    FILE *cfPtr;
    int matricola_in, matricola, nEsami, codEsame, voto;
    char nome[20], cognome[20];
    int i, j, trovato = 0;
    float somma = 0.0;

    printf("Inserisci una matricola:\n");
    scanf("%d", &matricola_in);

    if( (cfPtr = fopen("studenti.txt", "r")) == NULL )
        printf("Errore");

    while( !feof(cfPtr) || trovato != 1 ){
        fscanf(cfPtr, "%d%s%s%d\n", &matricola, nome, cognome, &nEsami);
        if( matricola_in == matricola ){
            trovato = 1;
            for( i = 0; i < nEsami; i++ ){
                fscanf(cfPtr, "%d%d\n", &codEsame, &voto);
                somma += voto;
            }
            printf("Media: %.1f\n", somma/nEsami);
        }
    }

    fclose(cfPtr);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Edit: the data looks like:

```
matricola nome cognome n.esami`<eol>`
(for n.esami-rows)codice esame voto`<eol>`
...
```

Comment: Add a hexdump of the first few lines of `studenti.txt` -- try `hexdump -C studenti.txt | head`.  That may show you the answer immediately, but in any case will be helpful to other people answering.

Comment: What does the data look like?  Perhaps you have a student with more or fewer than 2 name components?  You also aren't setting the sum (`somma`) back to zero.  And you never want to control a loop with `feof`, instead check the return value from `fscanf`, and when it processed fewer fields than requested, then `feof` will tell you if the reason is reaching the end of file.

Comment: Edit: the data looks like: (matricola) (nome) (cognome) (n.esami)<eol> n.esami-rows: (codice esame) (voto) ...

Comment: the data does not have parenthesis. I wrote them for you to let you understand that is a "campo" to fill

Comment: Please edit the question with the additional information.

Comment: [why `while (!feof(cfPtr))` is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong)

Comment: Is that really the correct data? There are no numbers.

Comment: Always check that the value returned by `fscanf` is correct! Besides that you need to show us an example of studenti.txt where it fails

Comment: `codice esame voto` Hmm... is that two or three values?

Answer (score 1):

Not clear but it seems the file contains a mix of line that have either four or two items.
Consider reading each line. Parse the line into up to four strings using sscanf. As needed use `sscanf` to capture the integers from the line. If there are two items, process them if `trovato` flag indicates a match has been found. If there are four items, see if there is a match and set `trovato`.

```
int main ()
{
    FILE *cfPtr;
    int matricola_in, matricola, nEsami, codEsame, voto;
    char nome[20], cognome[20];
    char temp[4][20];
    char line[200];
    int result;
    int i, j, trovato = 0;
    float somma = 0.0;

    printf("Inserisci una matricola:\n");
    scanf("%d", &matricola_in);

    if( (cfPtr = fopen("studenti.txt", "r")) == NULL ) {
        printf("Errore");
        return 0;
    }

    while( fgets ( line, sizeof line, cfPtr)){//read a line until end of file
        result = sscanf ( line, "%19s%19s%19s%19s", temp[0], temp[1], temp[2], temp[3]);//scan up to four strings
        if ( result == 2) {//the line has two items
            if ( trovato) {// match was found
                sscanf ( temp[0], "%d", &codEsame);
                sscanf ( temp[1], "%d", &voto);
                somma += voto;
            }
        }
        if ( result == 4) {//the line has four items
            if ( trovato) {
                break;//there was a match so break
            }
            sscanf ( temp[0], "%d", &matricola);
            sscanf ( temp[3], "%d", &nEsami);
            if( matricola_in == matricola ){//see if there is a match
                trovato = 1;//set the flag
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Media: %.1f\n", somma/nEsami);//print results

    fclose(cfPtr);

    return 0;
}
```